# When I create branch from a particular commit(merge commit), some of the earlier commits are erased

Tags: git, github

I have a commit where 2 branches are merged. When I create a new branch out of that commit I dont see the commits of one of the branch involved in merge . The commits disappear from the commit history of this newly created branch.

Commit history:

```
A--B--C--D------H--I  <-- master  
       \       /  
        E--F--G   <-- develop
```

When I checkout from commit **H**, I dont see the **E, F and G** commits.
I used "create new branch from commit" in git desktop. I also tried checking out that commit in command line.

Comment: What's the "commit history"? What are "the changes of branch B"? (Git does not deal in "changes".) Please show the _actual commands_ you give to Git, and show us what Git says and what you were hoping for and why. Don't describe your code, show it.

Comment: @matt I have updated the problem description.

Comment: If you have `H` checked out, and if H is a merge commit of D and G, then it's not possible for E,F,G to be missing. But it's possible that you won't "see" them depending on how you are looking at them. What tool are you using to "see" them? Can you show the output or a screenshot of commit H with the others not being displayed? It's probably just a misunderstanding of the view.

Comment: You are still not answering my question; you are just re-expressing an unknown with another unknown. The words "I dont see the E, F and G commits" are meaningless. Give them meaning. Tell us _what you do_ in order to "see" them. How would you "see" a _commit?_ Are you giving a Git command? _What_ command?

Comment: What do you mean with "see"? How do you visualize the history? In other words: which command do you use to show it? Can you show the output (or a screenshot if it's a GUI tool) and where the commits are missing from the output?